# Jasmine - Spy on a function that is called in same file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, typescript, jasmine

This has bothered me for a while.  I have two functions in the same file.

```
//fun.ts

export function fun1(){
    let msg = fun2();
    return msg;
}

export function fun2(): string{
    return "Some message";
}
```

I have a typescript spec that stubs fun2 and calls fun1.

```
//fun.spec.ts

import * as Fun from 'fun';

describe('Stubing', () => {
    it('should stub the return value', () => {
        spyOn(Fun, 'fun2').and.returnValue("A different message");

        expect(Fun.fun1()).toEqual("A different message")
    });
});
```

But when I run the spec, the output I get is

```
Failures:
1) Stubing should stub the return value
1.1) Expected 'Some message' to equal 'A different message'.
```

I wrote the tests in typescript and then I have a gulp script that successfully transpiles and runs the jasmine specs.  Everything works, the only thing that I can't figure out is why the spy is not working.  An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this.  If you add an `expect(Fun.fun2()).toEqual("A different message")` does your test pass?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  In fun.ts, I am directly calling the fun2 object, but my Jasmine spec has no access to that object.  The only object the Jasmine spec can access is the exports object. If I want the spy to work I need to call fun2 on the exports object.

```
//fun.ts
export function fun1(){
    let msg = exports.fun2();
    console.log(msg);
}

export function fun2(): string{
    return "Some message";
}
```

Now when the spec executes I see

```
.
1 spec, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer! Works perfectly.